# How to access plugin from nuxt.js store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, gtag.js

I have this gtag (analytics plugin) that I can access on my components but never on my store.
I would appreciate any opinions. Thanks

plugins/vue-gtag.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag"

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: {
      id: process.env.ga_stream_id
    }
  })
}
```

store/gaUserProperty.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import { User } from "~/models/user/User"

export const states = () => ({})

const getterObjects = {}
const mutationObjects = {}
Object.keys(states).forEach(key => {
  getterObjects[key] = state => state[key]
  mutationObjects[key] = (state, value) => (state[key] = value)
})

export const state = () => states

export const getters = { ...getterObjects }

export const mutations = { ...mutationObjects }

export const actions = {
  async sendUserProperties({ dispatch, commit }) {
    let res = await this.$UserApi.getUser()
    if (!(res instanceof User)) {
    } else {
      // I can access this on my components and pages but for some reason not here....
      console.log(this.$gtag)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import this properly, I would export the instance (or any of its internals) from `main.(ts|js)`:

```
const Instance = new Vue({...whatever});

// only export what you need in other parts of the app
export const { $gtag, $store, $t, $http } = Instance;

// or export the entire Instance
export default Instance;
```

now you can import it in your store:

```
import Instance from '@/main';
// or: 
import { $gtag } from '@/main';

// use Instance.$gtag or $gtag, depending on what you imported.
```

---

As other answers mentioned, in current Vuex version the Vue instance is available under `this._vm` inside the store. I'd refrain from relying on it, though, as it's not part of the exposed Vuex API and not documented anywhere. In other words, Vuex developers do not guarantee it will still be there in future versions.
To be even more specific, Vue's promise is that all `v2` code will work in `v3`. But only if you use the exposed API's.

And the discussion here is not even on whether it will be removed or not (it most likely won't). To me, it's more a matter of principle: if it starts with a `_` and it's not documented, it translates into a message from authors: *"We're reserving the right to change this at any time, without warning!"*

Comment: Can you tell the equivalent of main.js in nuxt? I can't find one :<

Comment: ```import Vue from "vue"
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag"

Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: {
    id: process.env.ga_stream_id
  }
})

export default (ctx, inject) => {
  ctx.$gtag = Vue.$gtag
  inject("gtag", Vue.$gtag)
}```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the Vue instance through `this._vm` in the Vuex store, so you would just need to do:

```js
console.log(this._vm.$gtag)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It worked fine but the fact that it is not in the documentation worries me.

Comment: are there any other way to do it ?

Comment: @obliviousfella it's a Vue.js internal property so it's not actually documented but it works as an element of the Vue.js core functionality. I'm aware of the observations made in other answers but I'm also an advocate of the KISS principle, but anyways I guess it's a matter choosing which solution fits better for your particular need.

Answer (score 2):

According to nuxtjs the plugins are available in the store actions.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins

> Sometimes you want to make functions or values available across your
> app. You can inject those variables into Vue instances (client side),
> the context (server side) and even in the Vuex store. It is a
> convention to prefix those functions with a $.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31369308)